# How do I find out what frequencies an iPhone supports?

Tags: iphone

How do I find out what mobile phone frequencies an iPhone supports?  My wife has an old Australian 3G iPhone and we want to use it on a trip to the US, but we're not sure what mobile phone frequencies it supports and that may affect whether or not we can use it over there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [iPhone 3GS - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP565):

**Cellular and wireless**

- UMTS/HSDPA (850, 1900, 2100 MHz)
- GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)
- 802.11b/g Wi-Fi
- Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR wireless technology

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands):

> In North America, GSM operates on the primary mobile communication bands 850 MHz and 1,900 MHz. In Canada, GSM-1900 is the primary band used in urban areas with 850 as a backup, and GSM-850 being the primary rural band. In the United States, regulatory requirements determine which area can use which band.